# android ndk-build: error: unknown register name 'r0' in asm

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm buiding again [AndroidEagleEye](https://github.com/MindMac/AndroidEagleEye) library from source on MacOS. When I compile using `ndk-build` command, I meet this error:

> jni/base/hook.c:42:5: error: unknown register name 'r0' in asm
>                   :       "r0", "r1", "r7"

Here is the code with that error:

```
void inline hook_cacheflush(unsigned int begin, unsigned int end)

    {   
        const int syscall = 0xf0002;
        __asm __volatile (
            "mov     r0, %0\n"          
            "mov     r1, %1\n"
            "mov     r7, %2\n"
            "mov     r2, #0x0\n"
            "svc     0x00000000\n"
            :
            :   "r" (begin), "r" (end), "r" (syscall)
            :   "r0", "r1", "r7"
            );
    }
```

How can I fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndk-build` builds for all Android architectures. You need to either include asm for the other architectures as well (and guard them with the appropriate preprocessor macros), or set `APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a` in your Application.mk.

Comment: thanks. I understood. I have modify Application.mk and it's work. A litte more question, I compile and meet error when no return for return method. I must fixed by return 0 for all of those methods. Are there any options for ndk-build for by pass this ? (because I think the  original author has used some options for bypass those error). thanks

Comment: That warning is pretty fatal. The compiler can and will ruin your day if you have a function that's missing a return statement (it's undefined behavior, and you'll get all kinds of strange behaviors). If you really want to disable the warning, it's just `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=return-type`, but that's a pretty bad idea.